# steinmetz package comma problem

Tags: formatting, symbols, punctuation, vector, technical-environment

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}
$220\phase{0^{\circ}}$
$220\phase{0{,}5^{\circ}}$
$220\phase{0\phantom{{,}}\!\!^{\circ}}$   %<-- My solve
\end{document}
```

output

[image]

There are difference 0 and 0,5 horizontal line, added comma. Is there a automatic/macro solution?

Comment: No, unless you want the added space for the comma is used in all instances of `\phase`. By the way, `\phase{\vphantom{,}0^{\circ}}` is simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position of the angle depends on the material to be typeset inside it.

If you want that *all* `\phase` command produce the angle as if a comma is in the number, you can patch it as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\phase}{#2}{\vphantom{,}#2}{}{}

\begin{document}

$220\phase{0^{\circ}}$
$220\phase{0{,}5^{\circ}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, for the occasional fix when two of those `\phase` command appear next to each other, add a `\vphantom` yourself

```
\phase{\vphantom{,}0^{\circ}}
```